# Laravel add the ID of current user into the table when he adds a new entry

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, exception, foreign-keys

yeah so I have a user table with user id and another table of shelters, users will add shelters to the table and I want to show the user id of the person that adds that particular shelter to the table i am using   $table->foreignId('id')->references('id')->on('users'); that gives me
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'id' doesn't have a default value

Shelter Table

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('animal_shelters', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id('shelter_id');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->foreignId('id')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->string('shelter_name');
            $table->string('shelter_address');
            $table->string('shelter_mobile_number');
            $table->string('shelter_type');
        });
    }
```

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->foreignId('current_team_id')->nullable();
            $table->string('profile_photo_path', 2048)->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Error :

Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'id' doesn't have a default value

inserting into database

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
$Animal_shelter = new Animalshelter();
$Animal_shelter->shelter_name = $request->input('shelter_name');
 $Animal_shelter->shelter_address = $request->input('shelter_address');
 $Animal_shelter->shelter_mobile_number = $request->input('shelter_mobile_number');
 $Animal_shelter->shelter_type = $request->input('shelter_type');
  $Animal_shelter->save();
  return redirect()->back()->with('status', 'shelter added successfully');
    }
```

Comment: Don't call your foreign key `id`... `id` is typically reserved for the primary, auto-incrementing key. Use `user_id`, referencing `id` on `users`. Also, you'll need to show the code where you're trying to insert this record; you likely just forgot to reference it.

Comment: i forgot to add   $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id'); before it ! but I wanted to know will it be assigned automatically to whoever adds the shelter details? like a user with user id 2 adds a shelter will the shelter record say user id 2 without anyone having to edit it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just because you not set the `user_id` field. simply add it to your object before `save()` will fix the problem

```php
$Animal_shelter->user_id = auth()->id() // In case you need to get authenticated user id
```

Or just change your shelter migration file so the column accept null value

```php
$table->foreignId('user_id')->nullable()->constrained();
```

Or last solution, if you set up relationship between User and Shelter on eloquent level, you can chain function, something like this

```php
auth()->user()->shelters()->create(['your data']);
```

[Second solution](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/migrations#column-modifiers)
[Third solution](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#the-create-method)

Answer (score 0):

No, it won't add it automatically. When you add to the shelter table you must set the foreignid to the user id of the user that is creating it.

Comment: hi i have added my code for inserting data into database i am using a simple for where users can just update details without any roles and stuff that why i need to ahve their ids to get hold of trolls i guess i need to use session to add the key i am not sure